# Passt das Wort Pflege zu der Präposition gegen?

Tags: preposition

Passt das Wort Pflege zu dem Präposition **gegen**?

`z.B. Pflege gegen Paradontose.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Der Ausdruck "Pflege gegen Parodontose" sollte nicht verwendet werden. Er ist zwar durchaus verständlich, klingt aber schief. Man kann (abhängig vom Kontext) sagen

- Zahnpflege zum Schutz vor Parodontose
- Zahnpflege zur Parodontosevorsorge
- Anti-Parodontose-Zahnpflege

Comment: Danke Schön !!!!!